# selenium scrape table and converting to csv file

Tags: dataframe, selenium, csv, html-table

```
 import time
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
 import pandas as pd


options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
s = Service(r'C:\Users\jojob\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\98.0.4758.102\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
url = "https://www.nba.com/"

driver.get(url)  # open a new tab in the new window
time.sleep(2)
# when the element is visible, cklick it
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
players = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='nav- 
ul']/li[10]/a/span[1]")))
players.click()

search_player = wait.until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//* 
 [@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[3]/section/div/div[1]/div/input')))
 search_player.send_keys("antetokounmpo")
 search_player.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
 time.sleep(1)
 giannis = wait.until((EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                                    "//* 
 [@id='__next']/div[2]/div[3]/section/div/div[2]/div["
                                                    
 "2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a/div[2]/p[1]")))) 
 giannis.click()
 time.sleep(2)

# get data from the table
table = wait.until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//* 
[@id='__next']/div[2]/div[5]/section[2]/div/div/div/table"))).get_attribute('outerHTML')                                  

df_table = pd.read_html(table)

print(df_table)
print(type(df_table))
```

I have write this code to scrape from this site one table(Last 5 Games, stats) and i want the result that i have to write them in a csv file.

this is my output:

```
[      Game Date      Matchup W/L  MIN  PTS  FGM  ...  AST  STL  BLK  TOV  PF  +/-
0  FEB 15, 2022  MIL vs. IND   W   36   50   17  ...    4    0    0    3   3    7
1  FEB 10, 2022    MIL @ PHX   L   30   18    5  ...    8    0    1    3   1  -18
2  FEB 08, 2022    MIL @ LAL   W   35   44   17  ...    8    1    2    0   5   23
3  FEB 06, 2022    MIL @ LAC   W   31   28    8  ...    5    1    2    2   2   14
4  FEB 05, 2022    MIL @ POR   W   25   29    7  ...    6    0    1    1   1   28

[5 rows x 23 columns]]
<class 'list'>
```

how i can convert that list to csv file with columns and rows?
to looks like the table on the site

[image]

Comment: df_table.to_csv('filename.csv')  if you grab the table instead.

Comment: i have already tried that and i recive: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'. I have try also to make it Dataframe frame before to save it df_table = pd.DataFrame(df_table) and i recive this error : raise ValueError(f"Must pass 2-d input. shape={values.shape}")
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 5, 23)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get there using BeautifulSoup interim to Pandas; please see below.

```
import time
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
 import pandas as pd


options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
s = Service(r'C:\Users\jojob\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\98.0.4758.102\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
url = "https://www.nba.com/"

driver.get(url)  # open a new tab in the new window
time.sleep(2)
# when the element is visible, cklick it
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
players = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='nav- 
ul']/li[10]/a/span[1]")))
players.click()

search_player = wait.until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//* 
 [@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[3]/section/div/div[1]/div/input')))
 search_player.send_keys("antetokounmpo")
 search_player.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
 time.sleep(1)
 giannis = wait.until((EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                                    "//* 
 [@id='__next']/div[2]/div[3]/section/div/div[2]/div["
                                                    
 "2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a/div[2]/p[1]")))) 
 giannis.click()
 time.sleep(2)

# get data from the table
table = wait.until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//* 
[@id='__next']/div[2]/div[5]/section[2]/div/div/div/table"))).get_attribute('outerHTML')                                  

soup = BeautifulSoup(table,'html.parser')
df_table = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]
csvFile = pd.DataFrame.to_csv(df_table)


print(df_table)
print(type(df_table))
```

Comment: it works like that!!! Thank you a lot @Shawn Ramirez